# Generate custom waveform in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to generate waveform in verilog using the code below but the result aren't as expected.

```
initial begin
    d = 1'b0;
#8  d <= 1'b1;
#15 d <= 1'b0;
end
```

Its initial value is 0(OK), at t=8, its 1(OK) but at t=23, its 0. Instead i want it to be 0 at t=15 relative to t=0 and not to t=8(i.e. previous statement).

Is there a way to do so? I have tried interchanging blocking and non-blocking assignments but no luck!

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
initial fork
    d = 1'b0;
#8  d = 1'b1;
#15 d = 1'b0;
join
```

All the statements inside `fork join` will be executed *concurrently*.

Or you could do this:

```
initial     d = 1'b0;
initial  #8 d = 1'b1;
initial #15 d = 1'b0;
```

Clearly, the three initial blocks will be executed concurrently.

If you really wanted to schedule 3 events from *procedural* (sequential) code, then you could do this:

```
initial begin
  d  =     1'b0;
  d <=  #8 1'b1;
  d <= #15 1'b0;
end
```

This uses *intra-assignment delays* together with non-blocking assignments.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4MiS

Comment: Does that mean using inter-assignment delays advance the simulation time?

Comment: @devvaibhav I'm not sure what you mean exactly. However, section9.4.5 of IEEE1800-2012 ("Intra-assignment timing controls") says "An intra-assignment delay or event control shall delay the assignment of the new value to the left-hand side, but the right-hand expression shall be evaluated before the delay, instead of after the delay.". If you add an intra-assignment delay to a non-blocking assignment, then execution continues immediately after and the assignment occurs after the delay. So, you are effectively scheduling an event to take place some time in the future.